# Kivy list in alphabetical order

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I cant find a way to do a list in alphabetical order in kivy...
This is a list were I want in alphabetical order.
For example I put my .kv code list here.

```
<Mercado>:
#:import sys sys
#:import lv kivy.uix.listview
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter
[CustomListItem@SelectableView+BoxLayout]:
    size_hint: None, None
    height: 70
    width: 400
    ListItemButton:
        text: ctx.text
        font_size: '40sp'
<ListViewModal>:
    list_view: list_view_id
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 0.5, 1
        ListView:
            id: list_view_id
            adapter:
                la.ListAdapter(
                data=[
                "Feijão",
                "Bolo",
                "Arroz Tio - João da Fazenda do Nordeste",
                "Carne bovina",
                "Pão de Forma",
                "Queijo",
                "Cheddar",
                "Alface",
                "Pão Francês",
                "Chá",
                "Sal",
                "Oregano",
                "Alho",
                "Miojo",
                "Molho de tomate",
                "Papel Toalha",
                "Macarrão",
                "Manteiga",
                "Papel higienico",
                "Melão",
                "Coca-Cola",
                "Café",
                "Abobrinha",
                "Brócolis",
                "Suco de uva",
                "Suco de laranja",
                "Água de cocô",
                "Aveia",
                "Leite Condensado",
                "Tomate",
                "Berinjela",
                "Laranja",
                "Maçã",
                "Leite",
                "Achocolatado",
                "Açucar"
                ],
                selection_mode='multiple',
                allow_empty_selection=True,
                list_item_args_converter=sys.modules['__main__'].list_item_args_converter,
                template='CustomListItem')
```

I just wanna make in alphabetical order, just that.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the `sorted` method that applies to a `list` and returns its sroted counterpart.

Build your object like this:

```
la.ListAdapter(
            data=sorted([
            "Feijão",
            "Bolo",
            "Arroz Tio - João da Fazenda do Nordeste",
            <..snip..>
            "Maçã",
            "Leite",
            "Achocolatado",
            "Açucar"
            ]),
            <..to be continued..>
```

Comment: It's that simple =D
Thank you very much.